# Why checkSelfPermission() is throwing a NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I'm checking for phone call permission when a `call button` in listview is pressed. For some reason the `Context` I'm passing as a parameter in `checkSelfPermission()` method is causing the null pointer exception. I've used `this`, `ActivityName.this`, `getContext()`, `getApplicationContext()`. None of them is working for me.
**Note:** Call to the `makephonecall()` method is initiated from my adapter class on listview button pressed.

```
public void makephonecall()
    {
        try {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(BloodVaultActivity2.this,
                    Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(BloodVaultActivity2.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_CALL);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CALL)
        {
            if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                makephonecall();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Adapter class:**

```
package bd.edu.bubt.regup;

import android.*;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BloodVaultAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BloodVaultItem> {

    ArrayList<BloodVaultItem> adapterlist = new ArrayList<>();
    int REQUEST_CALL = 1;

    public BloodVaultAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<BloodVaultItem> objects){

        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        adapterlist = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){

        return super.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blood_vault_list_view_layout, null);

        TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView group = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.group);
        Button call = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.call);

        call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                BloodVaultItem bloodVaultItem = getItem(position);

                String number = bloodVaultItem.getContact();

                BloodVaultActivity2 bloodVaultActivity2 = new BloodVaultActivity2();
                bloodVaultActivity2.number = number;
                bloodVaultActivity2.makephonecall();
            }
        });

        name.setText("Name: " +adapterlist.get(position).getName());
        group.setText("Blood Group: " +adapterlist.get(position).getGroup());

        return v;
    }
}
```

**Logcat:**

```
06-13 01:42:36.920 13102-13102/bd.edu.bubt.regup W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)' on a null object reference
06-13 01:42:36.921 13102-13102/bd.edu.bubt.regup W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ContextCompat.java:430)
06-13 01:42:36.921 13102-13102/bd.edu.bubt.regup W/System.err:     at bd.edu.bubt.regup.BloodVaultActivity2.makephonecall(BloodVaultActivity2.java:182)
06-13 01:42:36.921 13102-13102/bd.edu.bubt.regup W/System.err:     at bd.edu.bubt.regup.BloodVaultAdapter$1.onClick(BloodVaultAdapter.java:63)
06-13 01:42:36.921 13102-13102/bd.edu.bubt.regup W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
06-13 01:42:36.921 13102-13102/bd.edu.bubt.regup W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
06-13 01:42:36.921 13102-13102/bd.edu.bubt.regup W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
06-13 01:42:36.922 13102-13102/bd.edu.bubt.regup W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-13 01:42:36.922 13102-13102/bd.edu.bubt.regup W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
06-13 01:42:36.922 13102-13102/bd.edu.bubt.regup W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
06-13 01:42:36.922 13102-13102/bd.edu.bubt.regup W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-13 01:42:36.922 13102-13102/bd.edu.bubt.regup W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
06-13 01:42:36.922 13102-13102/bd.edu.bubt.regup W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
06-13 01:42:36.928 1382-1455/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 137954329 , only wrote 137954160
06-13 01:42:36.975 1382-1455/? W/audio_hw_generic: Hardware backing HAL too slow, could only write 0 of 720 frames
06-13 01:42:40.154 1382-1456/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 138261974 , only wrote 138108960
06-13 01:43:28.433 2223-8977/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher I/ClearcutLoggerApiImpl: disconnect managed GoogleApiClient
01-01 00:00:00.000 0-0/? E/Internal: device offline
```

Comment: Please provide the crash logs.

Comment: @Astha added to my post. please check.

Comment: Use an interface

Comment: @ManojPerumarath You mean handle the makephonecall() method from interface?

Comment: Unrelated: read about java naming conventions. Variables names go camelCase. Only class names go UpperCase. I assume `ContextCompat` is a very misleading name for a variable/field.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. You are showing the method that **obviously** invokes a method on a null field `ContextCompat` ... but you are showing zero code where/how that field gets initialized!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a solution for this problem. I just combined the solution of [Astha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8762338/astha) and [Manoj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5351055/manoj-perumarath) from their answers [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56573736/6349465) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56573418/6349465).

First I caught the `context` of my `adapter` class using:

```
Context context;

    public BloodVaultAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<BloodVaultItem> objects){

        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
        adapterlist = objects;
    }
```

Second pass that `context` as a parameter of `makephonecallmethod()` from `adapter` class:

```
call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                BloodVaultItem bloodVaultItem = getItem(position);

                String number = bloodVaultItem.getContact();

                BloodVaultActivity2 bloodVaultActivity2 = new BloodVaultActivity2();
                bloodVaultActivity2.number = number;
                bloodVaultActivity2.makephonecall(context);
            }
        });
```

Third use the passed `context` as a parameter of `checkSelfPermission()` inside `Activity` class:

```
Context mcontext;

public void makephonecall(Context context)
    {
        this.mcontext = context;

        try {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(BloodVaultActivity2.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_CALL);
            } else {
                String dial = "tel:" + number;
                context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(dial)));
            }
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CALL)
        {
            if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                makephonecall(mcontext);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `context`(received in Constructor of Adapter) in place of `BloodVaultActivity2.this` i.e.

`ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)`

Also,
BloodVaultActivity2 bloodVaultActivity2 = new BloodVaultActivity2();
is incorect way of calling method as this will create new instance of your activity, instead typeCast your `context` to `BloodVaultActivity2` & pass `this` from your Activity in constructor of Adapter :

```
if(mContext instanceof YourActivityName){
       ((YourActivityName)mContext).yourActivityMethod();
}
```

Btw a better approach for interaction between Activity & Adapter is using interface.
https://android.jlelse.eu/click-listener-for-recyclerview-adapter-2d17a6f6f6c9

Comment: The typecast accomplishes exactly nothing.

Comment: Why do you think so? We need to call the existing Activity's method instead of calling method of new Activity.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: The root cause is you are creating a new Instance of the activity on item click, hence you are seeing the null pointer. Since you are already passing context in your adapter do it in the way shown by Manoj in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56573418/3318025

Comment: @Sajib - share the crash logs. Ideally getApplicationContext() should not come null when app is running.

Comment: added to my post. please check.

Comment: @sajib - share the adapter code where you are calling makephonecall(). Most probably it should be fixed there. Also, add how you are initializing the adapter.

Comment: Tried but getting error- java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to bd.edu.bubt.regup.BloodVaultActivity2

Comment: Seems you are passing ApplicationContext while instantiating Adapter, pass 'this' from your Activity

Answer (score 0):

If you create an object of a class using

```
BloodVaultActivity2 bloodVaultActivity2 = new BloodVaultActivity2();
            bloodVaultActivity2.number = number;
            bloodVaultActivity2.makephonecall();
```

It won't call the function, since it is an activity class which has life cycle aware methods, one way is to create an interface invoke the function using context or cast the context to your activity which has the method you want to run
Change it like,

```
   public class BloodVaultAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BloodVaultItem> {
   Context context;

   public BloodVaultAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, 
   ArrayList<BloodVaultItem> objects){
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context=context;
    adapterlist = objects;
}
```

then,

```
call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            BloodVaultItem bloodVaultItem = getItem(position);

            String number = bloodVaultItem.getContact();
            (( BloodVaultActivity2)context).makephonecall();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Change it why? Mere code is not an answer. You have to explain. What is `context(BloodVaultActivity2)`?

Comment: Getting Expression expected error under context(BloodVaultActivity2).

Comment: @Sajib I'm not surprised. I think he intended an unexplained typecast, but it isn't.

Comment: @user207421 I'm struggling to find a solution. If you can help I'll be really thankful.

Comment: @ManojPerumarath Getting error -  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to bd.edu.bubt.regup.BloodVaultActivity2

Comment: Seems you are passing ApplicationContext while instantiating Adapter, pass 'this' from your Activity

Comment: @Sajib replace getapplicationcontext with bloodvaultactivity2

Comment: Working now. Tried passing the adapter context as a parameter of makephonecallmethod(). Thank you.